# Python: PerformanceWarning: Adding/subtracting object-dtype array to TimedeltaArray not vectorized

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame `DF` with 2 date columns (object data type) in the below format:

```
date_column1 date_column2
2021-08-14    2021-09-19
2021-10-11    2021-11-02
2019-09-15    2021-10-25
...           ...
```

and I want to insert a new column based the below:

```
DF['date_new'] = DF['date_column2'] + (DF['date_column2']-DF['date_column1'])
```

The code works but I am getting the below warning

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimelike.py:1190: 
PerformanceWarning: Adding/subtracting object-dtype array to TimedeltaArray not vectorized
```

How should I adapt my code to fix this warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simulated with your sample data, the situation happens when your `date_column1` is of string type while `date_column2` is of datetime type.  Other combinations give other kind of errors.  When both are in datetime type, there is no error.

You will get through the warning by converting `date_column1` also to datetime type, as follows:

```
DF['date_column1'] = pd.to_datetime(DF['date_column1'])

# or to play safe, also convert `date_column2`
DF['date_column2'] = pd.to_datetime(DF['date_column2'])
```

After that, you will get successful result as follows without warning:

```
0   2021-10-25
1   2021-11-24
2   2023-12-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```