# Overcome Performance warning in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
mydata = [{'ID' : '10', 'StartDate': '10/10/2016', 'EndDate': '15/10/2016'},
          {'ID' : '20', 'StartDate': '10/10/2016', 'EndDate': '18/10/2016'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)

df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate']).dt.date
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate']).dt.date
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat((df['EndDate'] - df['StartDate']).dt.days + 1)]
df['Date'] = df['StartDate'] + pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='d')
```

I am getting Performance warning :

> PerformanceWarning: Adding/subtracting object-dtype array to
> TimedeltaArray not vectorized.

What can I do to make it vectorized?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69644304/python-performancewarning-adding-subtracting-object-dtype-array-to-timedeltaar article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix the issue.

`pandas` complained about dayfirst not set for dates like "%d/%m/%Y".
Removed `.dt.date` that prevent pandas to set dtype to `datetime64` and caused the warning.

```py
mydata = [{'ID' : '10', 'StartDate': '10/10/2016', 'EndDate': '15/10/2016'}, {'ID' : '20', 'StartDate': '10/10/2016', 'EndDate': '18/10/2016'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)

df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'], dayfirst=True)
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'], dayfirst=True)
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat((df['EndDate'] - df['StartDate']).dt.days + 1)]
df['Date'] = df['StartDate'] + pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='d')
```

Before

```
StartDate    object
EndDate      object
```

After

```
StartDate    datetime64[ns]
EndDate      datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

For vectorized solution need datetimes instead `dates`:

```
df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'], dayfirst=True)
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'], dayfirst=True)
```

If there are times and need remove them use [`Series.dt.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) instead `dt.date`:

```
df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'], dayfirst=True).dt.normalize()
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'], dayfirst=True).dt.normalize()
```

---

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat((df['EndDate'] - df['StartDate']).dt.days + 1)]
df['Date'] = df['StartDate'] + pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='d')
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
    ID  StartDate    EndDate       Date
0   10 2016-10-10 2016-10-15 2016-10-10
1   10 2016-10-10 2016-10-15 2016-10-11
2   10 2016-10-10 2016-10-15 2016-10-12
3   10 2016-10-10 2016-10-15 2016-10-13
4   10 2016-10-10 2016-10-15 2016-10-14
5   10 2016-10-10 2016-10-15 2016-10-15
6   20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-10
7   20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-11
8   20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-12
9   20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-13
10  20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-14
11  20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-15
12  20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-16
13  20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-17
14  20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-18
```